# How can I dual boot 2 linux distros Keeping One as my primary and constantly change the second?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I would like to Dual boot my secondary laptop. I want to keep one Linux Distro (Lets take Ubuntu..!) as my daily driver and try out different distros like Linux Mint, Fedora, Manjaro....etc. How can I configure my GRUB for constantly changing secondary distro?? I don't want to keep common /home folder for them; I just want to try out different distros for a week or may be couple of weeks. Please suggest me a good way to do it. (Basically I am distrohopper). 
I am having Legacy BIOS.

Comment: If you just want to try out different distros why don't you use Live System? Then you like it, you can install your choosen distro.

Comment: I want to play around that distro for couple of weeks. So I don't want to use Live System. I want to see how actually that distro runs in my system.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep may Os systems, use gparted to create as many partitions as you would like Operating systems, then just install each OS on each partition.

If you only want one extra OS at a time, just create on extra partition with gparted and install the new OS on top of the older OS each time you want to change. In other words, install the new OS on the same partition of the one you would like to replace.

You won't have to worry about Grub as each OS you install will update grub and give you an OS selection menu at boot automatically.

Be very careful not to accidentally install on top of your primary OS (obviously). Memorize the partition of your primary OS (sda....).

Answer (score 0):

Why not install your distro's as virtual machines in VMware or VirtualBox? Much easier to remove a VM than clearing a partition/modifying grub with all possible risks of typos.

Comment: I am doing this experimentation in my secondary laptop. I have my primary laptop where I install different os in virtualbox. I want to try how actually that distro will run in my secondary laptop.

Comment: I trust the 2 laptops are hardware-wise 100% equal. In that case go with the advice given by PR88.